# How to make empty column in the end of table that contains no value

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to make a empty column. I tried this

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.", 
   CODE_BRANCH.branch_name AS "Business Unit",
   CODE_STAFF.staff_name AS "RM",
   to_date(:endDate, 'dd.mm.yyyy')  - LOSA_APP_Z.li_dt AS "Day Count",
   ...,
   (select "RemarK By SDS" from dual)
from
    losa_app LOSA_APP
INNER JOIN
    code_branch CODE_BRANCH
ON
    LOSA_APP.attend_branch = CODE_BRANCH.branch_id
....
where 
    LOSA_APP.app_status='A'; -- Application Status in {‘accepted’}
```

But i am getting error that

```
ORA-00904: "RemarK By SDS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 22 Column: 16
```

Line 22 is `(select "RemarK By SDS" from dual)`. Actually i just want to add this empty column in the end for remarks. This column contain no value.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.", 
   CODE_BRANCH.branch_name AS "Business Unit",
   CODE_STAFF.staff_name AS "RM",
   to_date(:endDate, 'dd.mm.yyyy')  - LOSA_APP_Z.li_dt AS "Day Count",
   ...,
   '' as "RemarK By SDS"
from
    losa_app LOSA_APP
.....
```

Instead of `(select "RemarK By SDS" from dual)` use just `'' as "RemarK By SDS"` it gives you empty column at the end of result set.